# Lost my github credentials; Now being prompted for username and getting an error

Tags: git, github

I had to do a coding challenge last night that involved cloning a github repo. It was a hot mess and I frantically changed a bunch of settings trying to get it to work. Now, it appears that my personal account is broken as when I try to push code this morning, I get an authentication request and it fails.

Here is what happens:

```
git push origin master
(response from terminal)
Username for 'https://github.com':(I enter my email)
Password for '(my email)@github.com': (I enter my password)
remote: Invalid username or password.
```

I deleted the ssh key last night and uploaded a new one. I am sure that has something to do with it. I am also not sure why it is adding the @github to my email when I enter it.

Comment: You're using `https` (HTTP over port 443, with SSL/TLS), not ssh (different port, different authentication and encryption method). Check the URL in your repository.

Comment: Check what URL? Check it for what? I've already cloned and been working in the repo for a while. This only started today?

Comment: If you do `git remote -v`, does your `origin` look right? If you are using your email, you want the ssh version, not the https version. Your remote should not start with https if you login with email. If you want to use https, you have to login with your github username. For ssh (login with email), use `git@github.com:<youraccountname>/project.git`

Comment: The remote origin seems to be pointing towards the same location, but it does start with 'https'. So, why has this been working up until today if it was done incorrectly? Do I just have to reclone with ssh?

Comment: I don't know for sure why it is not working today, but you asked about ssh, and yet you showed Git output using https. That's why I commented: if you want Git to use ssh protocol, rather than ssh protocol, you need to give Git an ssh URL, not an https URL. The URL is normally stored in your Git repository under a *remote* (short but easily remembered name); the standard first remote is `origin`. The `git remote` command manipulates the list of remotes, among other things it can do.

Comment: @torek They're not pushing away from HTTPS in general, they're requiring use of a personal access token instead of your GitHub account password. The brownouts were on June 30 and July 28 to raise awareness and help people find systems that are still using an account password. For more information: https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

- your GitHub user account name, not email
- a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as password, especially since Dec. 2020, and the [Token authentication requirements for Git operations](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

Check also your `git config credential.helper`: it could have cached another user/email/password.
If that setting is `xxx`, type:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"| git-credential-xxx get
```

You will check if there is any credential already stored.